# PHP Warning: strpos

Tags: php, strpos

So I have looked everywhere and I couldn't fimd the solution to my problem. I am using steam OpenID, and I keep getting this message: Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Offset not contained in string.

```
    if(($host_end = strpos($this->trustRoot, '/', 8)) !== false) {
        $this->trustRoot = substr($this->trustRoot, 0, $host_end);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple enough, it's complaining that the offset you're giving for the start of the search (8) is not contained within the string.

In other words, `$this->trustRoot` is too short for your initial offset.

You can see this in action if you head on over to [an online PHP tester site](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and enter:

```
echo strpos("abc","a",42);
```

The output is the same as you see, something like:

> `Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string on line 1`

The fix is to ensure your string is long enough before attempting the search, as with:

```
if (strlen ($this->trustRoot) > 8) {
    if(($host_end = strpos ($this->trustRoot, '/', 8)) !== false) {
        $this->trustRoot = substr ($this->trustRoot, 0, $host_end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the length of the string before trying to reference past character 8:

```
if (strlen($this->trustRoot) > 8 && ($host_end = strpos($this->trustRoot, '/', 8) !== false) {
    ...
}
```